# How to Update model and database with code first approach in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to `mvc`. I've creted an `MVC` app, in which i have used `code first` approach. Right now i have two tables **Deal** and **Comment**. Now i want to add a new table **Category** in the database and new column **categoryId** in **Deal** table.

How i can update database and model?

I'm using `Sql Server 2008 R2` for Database.

**I've following structure of class:**

```
      namespace FBWebApp.Models
    {
        public class Deal
      {
        public int ID { get; set; }                 // ID
        public string Title { get; set; }           // Titolo del deal   
        public string Description { get; set; }     // Descrizione dell'annuncio
        public string FacebookUID { get; set; }     // UID facebook dell'utente
        public string Visibility { get; set; }      // Visibility
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public int Option1 { get; set; }
        public int Option2 { get; set; }
        public int Option3 { get; set; }
        public int Option4 { get; set; }
        public string PhotoURL { get; set; }    // URL of the facebook photo profile 
        public string Name { get; set; }        // Name of the user
        public string ProfileUrl { get; set; }  // URL of the facebook profile
        public string Photo1 { get; set; }  // URL of the Photo1 (local )
        public string Photo2 { get; set; }
        public string Photo3 { get; set; }
        public string Photo4 { get; set; }
        public string Photo5 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Comment
    {
        [Key]
        public int CommentId { get; set; }
        public string CommentText { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ID")]
        public Deal DelNav { get; set; }
    }

    public class DealDBContext : DbContext
    {

        public DealDBContext() : base("DealDBContext") { }
        public DbSet<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: yes sure, if you can. I wrote in question "Now i want to add a new table Category in the database and new column categoryId in Deal table"

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take a look into Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Comment: Have you tried [Code First Migration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)?

Comment: @AntP I was following this link http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-new-field-to-the-movie-model-and-table     but getting error.

Comment: @Grumbler85 I tried but its not working.

Comment: "it's not working" is not a viable error report.

Comment: Do you need to persist the data? If not then you can hook in a DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges database initializer to do what the name says it does.

Comment: Migrations has been enabled successfully, Now how i can update database in `SqlServer 2008 R2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add your model :

```
public class Category
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int cateName { get; set; }
}
```

in `Deal` class :

```
public class Deal
    {
        //..
         [ForeignKey("CatId")]
         public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

after [Enable Migration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) you should use this command in console manager to update your database :

```
update-database
```

Comment: I tried to enable migration but getting this error : `The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check th
e spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: try this command :  `Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease` and once again use `Enable-Migrations`

Comment: I already used this command `Install-Package EntityFramework`

Comment: Migrations has been enabled successfully, Now how i can update database in `SqlServer 2008 R2`

Answer (score 2):

Try using 'update-database -force -verbose' in the Package Manager Console.

If it doesn't work, modify the migration but typing 'add-migration somename' and it will apear in the Migrations folder.

If you are new to MVC and EF, definitely check out this tutorial. It explains all about that and everything else you need to know:

http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m1-intro&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building