# Error on trying to Update-Database code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to update my db after adding a few classes that need to be tables in the database.

I'm getting the following Error:

```
There is already an object named 'Blogs' in the database.
```

My data context  look like  this (the 3 last line are the table I need to add to my db):

```
public class WowDataContext : DbContext
{
    public WowDataContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    { }
    public DbSet<Genre> Ganres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TakeAway> TaKeAways { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Gellery> Galleries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<katering> Katring { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Events> events { get; set; }
    //i need to add this folowing 3 tables
    public DbSet<Order> orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

the hole update Db look like this :

[http://pastebin.com/CTwbz6Wj[1](http://pastebin.com/CTwbz6Wj)

and my Db migration look like this Image
![Migration table][2]`

[image: Db table]

Comment: You need to run the update-database command.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308831/how-to-update-model-and-database-with-code-first-approach-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Yes I have tried this, I have also re run this :Add-Migration 201403251531583_InitialCreate
Re-scaffolding migration '201403251531583_InitialCreate'.
Only the Designer Code for migration '201403251531583_InitialCreate' was re-scaffolded. To re-scaffold the entire migration, use the -Force parameter.. it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

**You could try the following:**

1. Delete all the migrations in your migrations folder (be careful - do not delete the configuration class file)
2. Run the `add-migration` command
3. Run `update-database` command

**If this does not work, and if this is in a test environment, then you could also do the following:**

1. Delete your database
2. Delete all the migrations in your migrations folder (be careful - do not delete the configuration class file)
3. Run the `add-migration` command
4. Run `update-database` command